# Map array nested inside an object in Angular 2

Tags: angular

How do I map the array underneath the BankCodes node?

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "BankCodes": [
    {
      "BankID": 1,
      "BankDescription": "Banamex",
      "BankName": "Banco Nacional de México",
      "BankStatus": 1
    },
    {
      "BankID": 2,
      "BankDescription": "Bancomext",
      "BankName": "Banco Nacional de Comercio Exterior SNC",
      "BankStatus": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is what I have for the service mapping:

```
  getBankInfos(): Observable<BankInfo[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._bankInfoUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <BankInfo[]> response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use JavaScript's dot accessor syntax on the result of the call to `.json()`.

```
  getBankInfos(): Observable<BankInfo[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._bankInfoUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <BankInfo[]> response.json().BankCodes)
        .do(data => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```